# Is the image a universal object?

Tags: category-theory, universal-property, monomorphisms

Given a function $f:X\to Y$ in category $\mathcal{C}$, one can construct the image as a factorisation $f=(e:I\hookrightarrow Y)\circ(g:X\to I)$ that is universal (initial) among all such factorisations.

This does seem like a [universal property](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3511678/trying-to-understand-the-definition-of-a-universal-property). But I can't figure out how this can actually be constructed as an initial object in a comma category, because there are morphisms both from and to the object.

Comment: It is not guaranteed that each morphism has an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\newcommand\Sub{\operatorname{Sub}}\Sub(Y)$ the preorder of subobjects of $Y$ in $\mathcal C$.
Then the "image functor" can be seen as a left-adjoint of the forgetful functor $\mathcal C/Y\leftarrow\Sub(Y)$.

In particular, if $f=e\circ g$ is an image factorization of $f$, then $g:(X,f)\to(I,e)$ is a universal arrow respect to the forgetful functor $\mathcal C/Y\leftarrow\Sub(Y)$.

If $\mathcal C/Y\leftarrow\Sub(Y):\Gamma$ denote such forgetful functor, then $((X,f),g)$ is an initial object in the comma category $(X,f)\downarrow\Gamma$.